# How to center the loading spinner on start of a PhoneGap app on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova, loading, splash-screen

On iPhones, during the initialization/loading of a PhoneGap application, there is an animated loading icon (spinner) in the top left of the screen (before the splash screen appears).

How can I make this appear in the center of the screen?

Comment: Can you confirm that this is not a native iPhone feature?

Comment: @Jivings I'm sorry, I really don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching for a customization too and found this great improvement on github:
[phonegap startup screen and loading indicator](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/pull/34)

You have to download and replace the file located in "PhoneGapLib/Classes/PhoneGapDelegate.m" and follow this steps:

> "This allows you to position the loading indicator to an arbitrary position on the screen. You simply specifiy the position in the PhoneGap.plist. The entry must be named "ActivityIndicatorPosition" and be of type Dictionary with the entries "Vertical" and "Horizontal". Vertical and Horizontal are values in percentage that describe the horizontal and vertical position on the screen. (e.g. Vertical: 50 and Horizontal: 50 center the loading indicator)"

This perfectly worked for me and even combines the splash screen with the loading indicator, which saves some seconds on startup.

Comment: Unfortunately since Apache picked up the project the github link is broken. I wasn't able to track down the referenced fix.

Comment: @GavinMiller if you are referring to the "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" plugin i have a modification to set the position of spinner  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735000/cordova-splash-screen-change-the-position-of-the-spinner/36736364#36736364