# How to set custom spinner on ionic 3 apps splash-screen

Tags: java, angular, ionic3, splash-screen

Hi i'm Developing Hybrid app using ionic-3. I want to set 'dots' Spinner at the place of default spinner but i didn't find any solution to do it. Exactly i want to do as like below example.

[Splash Example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=199UICkLoCoPIf2mehLWzRQKVygM0hwK4)

Answer (score 0):

The splash screen spinner is native, nothing ionic can do, you'll have to edit the android and ios platform separably in java and swift located here in your project:

platforms\ios\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-splashscreen\www

platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\splashscreen

First thing you probably should do is disable ionic spinner in your config.xml with:

```
 <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
```

example of similar thing: [Cordova splash screen change the position of the spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735000/cordova-splash-screen-change-the-position-of-the-spinner)

Maybe theres a plugin for what you want but I couldnt find one :,(